# nth derivative of a function to an arbitrary power

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How would one analytically write the following;

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(f(x)^k\right)$$

for integer $k$ and integer $n$?
Writing it for a specific $n$ is easy, however, is there a finite series (similar to the Stirling or Bell numbers) that will generate a correct solution?

Comment: Interesting problem. I know that $$ \frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}x^n} x^k = \frac{k!}{(k-n)!} x^{k-n}$$ but the problem above is more general.

Answer (score 2):

[Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) gives the $n$-th derivative of $g(f(x))$
so just take $g(y)=y^k$ therein.

Comment: Is there any advantage using Faa di Bruno's formula over using the one for higher products (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives)?